# iFrame in popup

Tags: facebook, iframe, web, popup

Since, my site is an online magazine, I'd like to make a custom reader for the articles. Thing is I'd like a pop-up iframe reader. Something like the Facebook photo theater. It pops up within the page and not as a separate window. In that pop up I'd like to put an iframe code. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply google for `javascript lightbox tutorial`. Or in case you use jQuery, there are dozens of plugins out there.

For example:

- [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/)
- [jQuery lightBox plugin](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/)
- [Lightbox 2](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)